# What is the port number for cassandra and solr?

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax

I read the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.0/opsc/reference/opscPorts_r.html) which says `7199` is `JMX port number` and `8983` is `solr port number` and `9160` is `cassandra client port number`. But if i start

```
  dse cassandra -s
```

starts solr. If i start cassandra-client in the same machine

```
  dse cassandra -f
```

It says

```
    Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 7199; nested exception is:
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

So I understand that both tries to use same JMX port number.

Is there any way to specify two port numbers one for solr or one for cassandra OR is there any way to start both in the same machine.

I am using datastax 2.2.2 tarball set up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to start dse one time. It runs search and c* in the same jvm and serves in all the ports you mentioned above.

As you mention above. Use this command for a tarball install to start dse in search mode. Do this accross your cluster (rolling restart, no downtime required):

```
bin/dse cassandra -s
```

Comment: How do i ensure that both are running? I understand your point. I just `netstat -plten` lists out all the ports

Comment: Hit cqlsh to interact with Cassandra. Hit the solr web admin console on your browser to interact with search. <Your nodes ip>:8983

Comment: Why 2.2.2? I mentioned on your other post 4.6.1 is the latest

Comment: What do you mean your production version? You asked for a way to confirm cassandra is running. One way of doing that is interacting with the database through cqlsh.

Comment: I mean that version 2.2.2 is currently used in my projects. is there any inks to get more info about `cql vs cli` ?

Comment: cql > thrift --> simplicity, maintenance, performance, to name a few. Check out our docs http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/thrift-to-cql3

Comment: Please specify the command to start all the services commonly

Comment: The command you are using now - dse cassandra -s from a tarball install starts dse in search mode which is c* + solr.